# Writing a code in excel to randomly pick a cell out of a set of certain cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of student names and a new column next to it that tells me wether a student has already given a presentation (in that case, the cell color is a certain value). I want to pick a student, who has not yet given a presentation, at random. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do it with a formula. List of students is in the column `A`. Column `B` is initially empty. Formula in `F1` shows the next student drawn.
Then you enter some mark in column `B` next to her/his name.
Next name is drawn. Caution: Formula is volatile, each time the sheet is recalculated there is a new result.
The formula in `F1`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER($A$2:$A$21,$B$2:$B$21=""), RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTBLANK($B$2:$B$21))),"DONE")
```

[image: Random Selection]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a script writing service, but here is the general way this is done:

1. Create a *sequentially numbered* set of students who have not yet given a presentation.
2. Use a random number in the range of 1 to the total number in that set to select an individual. (Or from zero to *n*-1 if you're a programmer ;-)
3. Reiterate procedure as students are removed from the set.